# Upload Multiple Images With Integer data Fields

Tags: flutter

**    I am using MultipartRequest to upload multiple images to the server but the backend developer told me i have to specify "category_id" field with integer value but fileds property in MultipartRequest accepts only Map here is my code what should i do?**

```
List images //hold the photos

//function to upload data 
uploadData() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> userId = await getUserData();

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Endpoint url);
    http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    request.headers.addAll({"Authorization": "Bearer ${await 
    userId["LastToken"]}"});

    request.fields["name"]="";
    request.fields["email"]="";
    request.fields["phone"]="";
    request.fields["description"]="";
    request.fields["category_id"]=1; //not working here it has to be String

    for (int i=0;i< images.length;i++){

// create multipart request

    ByteData byteData = await images[i].requestOriginal();
    List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    http.MultipartFile multipartFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
     'media[$i]',
      imageData,
      filename: images[i].name,
     );
      request.files.add(multipartFile);

    }

    var response = await request.send();
    var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
    var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
    print("response "+responseString);

   }
```

Comment: So did you get the solution ?

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Comment: @ios do you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Convert String to `int` in API side. I converted String to `int` in API side.

```
request.fields['id'] = currentCategoryid; // this is a string value
(int)$req->input('id') // php code
```

Comment: In front-end development most of developers don't control the api the consume.